# Rpy2 error: 'show' not found. Using Python 3.6 and R 3.4

Tags: rpy2

I am trying to use rpy2, but when I "import rpy2.robjects as robjects", I get a lot of warnings and this error:

Lookup Error: "show" not found. Here is the whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py", line 52, in <module>
    class RObjectMixin(object):
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py", line 66, in RObjectMixin
    __show = rpy2.rinterface.baseenv.get("show")
LookupError: 'show' not found
```

I know someone already asked a similar question, but those answers didn't help me and I was going to comment, but the instructions said to only comment if you are answering the question, so here I am asking my own.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and what worked for me:

1. Update `R` version to `3.5.0` [download R here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz)
2. Install `rpy2` package either with:

   - conda : `conda install -c r rpy2`
   - pip : `pip install rpy2`